# Finding login times in Linux

Tags: python, linux, unix, boot

I am trying to figure out times of logins into my systems (basically systems boot).

I am making use of `last` Unix command. However, it does not let me pull more than a certain number of entries. I assume that the log file from which it pulls, which is `/var/log/wtmp`, gets overwritten after a certain size.

I see that i have a `wtmp.1` file also, so using `-f` parameter i can go back a month further back the logs using this parameter. Wondering if logs further back are archived somewhere.

So, my question is: Is there a way to get older entries.

The following is the `last` call that i am making:

```
last -n 10000|grep "system"
```

Here are last few lines of the output

```
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-36-generic Sun Jul  7 07:07 - 22:08  (15:01)    
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-36-generic Sat Jul  6 23:23 - 23:23  (00:00)    
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-34-generic Sat Jul  6 09:40 - 23:22  (13:42)    
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-34-generic Sat Jul  6 09:38 - 09:39  (00:00)    
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-34-generic Sat Jul  6 06:40 - 09:39  (02:58)    
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-34-generic Sat Jul  6 06:15 - 06:17  (00:02)    
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-34-generic Sat Jul  6 06:13 - 06:17  (00:03)    
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-34-generic Fri Jul  5 19:30 - 22:34  (03:03)
```

I am not able to get logs further back in time.

1. Is this the correct approach?
2. How do we see older logs? For instance if i pass `-n 10000` or `-n 1000000`, i get the same output.

Eventually i will write a quick Python script to parse this o/p from subprocess module.

**EDIT** : Most of the answers below are correct. Unfortunately could accept only one answer. The logs once gone are gone!

Comment: boot time != login time. please change the title of your question. Good luck.

Comment: It seems what you are really asking is to how to increase (and possibly copy off to backup) the number of rotating wtmp logs.  For all practical purposes, unless unbeknowst to you your system is already doing this, the past data you want to look at is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't say what type of unix / linux you are running but on my Ubuntu hosts this works good for last boot times

```
for f in /var/log/wtmp*; do last -f $f reboot;done
```

All it does is find all the wtmp files in /var/log and then filter out the reboot user

Answer (score 2):

last searches back through the file /var/log/wtmp.
So regarding 2) it can only list those entries contained in wtmp. (use parameter f to specify any other file) E.g. if you rotate that file with a log rotator, it won't see those entries per default.
1) depends ;-)

You can only list those logins for which the log (resp. the rotate log are still present)

Answer (score 2):

The `last` command gets its information from the `wtmp` file (`/var/log/wtmp` on my current system, but depending on your distribution, the actual path may be different). That file is generally rotated on a regular basis in most distributions, and a certain number of previous files are kept, which you should be able to access using `last -f <filename>` (although you may need to uncompress older files first).

Comment: I have a `wtmp.1` file. Edited the question to reflect that. Can get back further 1 month. But i do not see archived older logs.

Answer (score 1):

cat /proc/uptime

This tells you how long the system has been up.
Is that what you want?

Comment: I actually need all previous logins. `uptime` only gives the uptime of the most recent login.